# Extension recommendation - Order List

Tags: orders, category, b2b, category-products

Looking for an extension recommendation (or alternative) for Order List functionality. A user should be able to enter quantities and order directly from a category listing page. Primarily used in B2B sites. Here's what I found so far: http://www.b2b-extensions.com/b2b-order-list.html

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at these. I think if you also search for Quick order you will find many examples. We have used a few so if you DM me I can give you others.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/quick-order-form-ajax-search.html

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/quick-order.html

Comment: Thanks @brentwpeterson I am looking for something more simpler. Just came across Advanced Quick Order http://www.magebright.com/advanced-quick-order.html Any experience with them?